# Issue with Deep Linking that doesn't work on android 13

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I want to use Deep links in my app using Jetpack Compose and Jetpack navigation.
I try to open the app using the link from google chrome but the app isn't opened and google chrome handle the request as if it is a regular website link.

I Tried to Use Deep linking with Jetpack Compose I did the following

- Defined The deep link in the composable

```
composable(
            route = "gyms/{gym_id}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(name = "gym_id") { type = NavType.IntType }),
            deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "https://gymsaround.example.com/details/{gym_id}"
                action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            })
        ) { GymDetailsScreen() }
```

- Defined Intent Filter in the Manifest

```
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <data
                        android:host="gymsaround.example.com"
                        android:scheme="https" />
                </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are mixing Deep Linking with App Linking. Have you placed `assetlinks.json` file in proper path (under proper url)?

```
https://gymsaround.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

as you have `android:autoVerify="true"` - this line makes Android check that domain is confirming that app can handle URL without opening web (browser app), some more doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks). if yes then app will automatically be opened without any prompt for user, if not still web page will be shown (as in your case) - this is App Linking

in short this gives no asking user for picking any app, your app will be picked (if verified), one step less, and cutting out option for picking "always" for web browser

if you just want to ask user at first click if he want to open URL in (your) app or in web browser then remove `autoVerify` flag, it's not part of Deep Linking and unneccessary always-failed domain check may probably break even picking option (marked as "untrusted app" or similar...)

Comment: Yes, I want to ask if he want to open the URL in the app or web browser.
I removed android:autoVerify="true" but the app didn't open too

Comment: did you fix the issue for android 13?

Answer (score 0):

Set the 2 sha256_cert_fingerprints one gets from your keystore file and another from the Google Play console App signing key certificate.
upload both to the https://yourdomain.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
like as below

```
 [
      {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
        "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "com.example.android",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
            "SH:A2:56:FR:OM:PL:AY:CO:NS:OL:EX:......"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
        "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "com.example.android",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
            "SH:A2:56:FR:OM:AN:DR:OI:DS:TU:DI:OO......"
          ]
        }
      }]
```

also, set AndroidManifest.xml like below

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="yourdomain.example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```